# C# Console App Suspends Sporadically After a While?

Tags: c#, memory, cpu-usage, suspend

I have a C# console app that is processing huge data in a `Parallel.For` loop.

But after a while my app suspends periodically(CPU-Usage falls down ),exactly in the same For-loop with same process.

CPU doesn't do anything on my app based on profiling information.

I guess it may be related to memory because it happens when memory usage reaches above 90%.

Thank you for your help.

[Image of CPU usage profiling  when Main is Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ewx5.png)

```
        feasiblePairs22222 = new List<Pair>();
        Pair[] tempPair = new Pair[tripListSize];
        Parallel.For(0, tripListSize, tri=>  {
           var PairingStack = new Stack<List<Trip>>();
           var firstElement = new List<Trip>();

            firstElement.Add(Program.tripList[tri]);
            PairingStack.Push(firstElement);

            while (PairingStack.Count > 0)
            {
                var tempPairing11 = PairingStack.Pop();
                int start = tempPairing11[tempPairing11.Count - 1].index;
                int startTime = tempPairing11[0].departureTime;
                foreach (Trip candidToAdd in twoTripMatchable[start])
                {
                        if (candidToAdd.araivalTime - startTime > Program.WorkingTimeLimit) { continue; }
                        if (candidToAdd.departureTime - tempPairing11[tempPairing11.Count - 1].araivalTime > 30) { continue; }
                        var newPairing = new List<Trip>();
                        newPairing.AddRange(tempPairing11);
                        newPairing.Add(candidToAdd);
                        PairingStack.Push(newPairing);

                        int workingTime = 0;
                        foreach (Trip currentTrip in newPairing) { workingTime = workingTime + currentTrip.Duration; }
                        if (workingTime <= 180) { continue; }
                        newPairing.ForEach(o => o.isCovered++);

                    lock (tempPair)
                        {
                            tempPair[tri] = new Pair();
                            tempPair[tri].PairTrips = newPairing.ToArray();
                            feasiblePairs22222.Add(tempPair[tri]);
                        }
                    }                        
                }
        });
```

Comment: I think there is not enough information in your question for us to deliver an exact answer? SO questions are not supposed to be answered with lists of "guesses" and "try.."

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would be pleased if you say what kind of information is needed to answer?

Comment: If you called your mechanic and said "my car is making a noise, what is wrong with it?" they would probably say "show me the car"

Comment: You likely have a deadlock.  We can't possibly diagnose why, given the lack of information.

Comment: @mehdifallahi Is there a reason you added code to the question, then removed that code?